# Substring compiles but code doesn't work

Tags: c#, substring

When I use the code below, it compiles but the rest of the code doesn't seem to work.  When I take out the Substring part of it, it does.

-Steps

```
String theDate, theWeekDay;     
if (ToTime(Time[0]) == ToTime(0, 0, 0))         
{
   theDate=ToDay(Time[0]).ToString().Substring(0,3);
   theWeekDay=Time[0].DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(4,8);
   DrawTextFixed("day",theWeekDay, TextPosition.BottomRight);
   DrawText("day"+Convert.ToString(ToDay(Time[0])),
   theWeekDay+" "+theDate,0, Low[0]-TickSize*20, Color.Blue);
}
```

Comment: Is that your *whole* code?

Comment: What are `theWeekDay` and `Time`? Where are thye declared and initialized? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work" more precisely

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: Re the new code: Where do ToTime() and ToDay() com from? signatures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to provide more than just this snippet of code. What is the Time object you're accessing via an indexer? Have you debugged this to see if `Time[0]` actually has a value? My guess here would be that `Time[0]` doesn't return a value that `DayOfWeek` can work with hence `Substring(0,3)` is being running against either an empty string or a `null` value

Comment: I was using substring in the wrong way, I thought that Substring(4,8) would take characters 4 through 8 and therefore I was getting an error because I was going beyond the number of chars in the string

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given enough information to solve your problem, but if you're just trying to get the day of the week name in the abbreviated format, use this instead:

```
theWeekDay = Time[0].ToString("ddd");
```

Comment: Although this does abbreviate it with two instead of desired three chars (btw, the same as `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedDayName(Time[0].DayOfWeek)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, It shouldn't. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx

Comment: I get this error:

**Error on calling 'OnBarUpdate' method for indicator 'Killzones3' on bar 71: Format String can be only "G", "g", "X", "x", "F", "f", "D" or "d".**

Comment: @Brandon: hmm, maybe it's different in germany and we get only two.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, probably. The culture formatting would likely be different. And Rik, you need to specify (in your question) what OnBarUpdate and Killzones3 are.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have omitted part of the code, your assignment does not take place within a class definition or a method.